# Why I do not caught socket timeout?

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

I do not understand, why in this code below I do not have the timeout (even if I set it with settimeout, I cant see the exception caught):

```
import socket

HOST = 'x.x.x.x'

open_ports = []
closed_ports = []

def scan(PORT):
    sock_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #sock_tcp.settimeout(0.5)
    SERVER_ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
    try:
        portStatusTCP = sock_tcp.connect_ex(SERVER_ADDR)
        if portStatusTCP==0:
            open_ports.append(PORT)
            print(str(PORT)+' is OPEN')
        else:
            closed_ports.append(PORT)
            print(str(PORT)+' is CLOSED')
    except socket.error as socketerror:
        print("ERROR"+socketerror)
    sock_tcp.close()

for PORT in range(15,25):
    print('scanning port: '+str(PORT))
    scan(PORT)

print(open_ports)
print(closed_ports)
```

Comment: the timeout exception is [`socket.timeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#exceptions), not `socket.error`.

Comment: Because [`connect_ex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect_ex) won't raise timeout exceptions

Comment: @t.m.adam: Even better!

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yeah, you get to know those things when working with Python sockets. `connect_ex` is a very handy feature.